# Duplicate items appearing in view? - Drupal 7

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

I've created a view block but when I run, duplicates are showing.

A snapshot of the view looks can be seen at:

[image: view snapshot]

You can see the duplicates in action at:

[image: block demo]

Any idea how I can prevent this from happening (the duplicate items both link to the same node/page)?

I've enabled aggregation, then looked into aggregation settings for my Content: Title FIELD.

However there doesn't seem to be a unique type option under aggregation type?

The options are:
- Group results together
- Count
- Count DISTINCT
- SUM
- Average
- Minimum
- Maximum
- Standard deviation

I have tried enabling Distinct and Pure Distinct. Neither seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I found a solution:

- Removed the check box "Pure distinct" leaving only Distinct checked within Query options (under advanced)
- Added a new field  (Content: Nid) - and choose count (DISTINCT) as the aggregation setting.

Answer (score 2):

In your view's advanced section and make sure you have the following option set:

- `Use aggregation` is set to true.

After enabling this option, you will find `Aggregation settings` link added next to Fields and Filter Criteria.

Use Node `nid` as the distinct value or group by `nid`, whichever better fits your needs.

Comment: Please confirm what you mean by "Use Node nid as the distinct value or group by nid"?

Comment: Add the `nid` as a field. then from `Aggregation settings` choose `count (DISTINCT)` option.

Comment: I was hoping you weren't going to say that! When I do this only one item shows?

Comment: BOOM! Fixed! I simply removed "Pure distinct" leaving just distinct under query options ticked!